# Server Side HTML include not always working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a project with lots of HTML pages (**no backend server**), to avoid lots of typing I wanted to include all the navigation menus (top and side) via an include.  So I'm using the following code.

I'm using Visual Studio (as a glorified text editor), when I start IE from Visual Studio, all works OK. When I browse directly to the file and open with IE, the navigation.html file isn't loaded.

The only difference I can see is that when started form VS, the URL is "http://localhost:60282/pages/index.html" as opposed to something like "C:\Users..\index.html"

I'm stuck and would really appreciate a dig out.

Thanks.

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<div id="nav-place-holder"></div>
```

```js
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-place-holder').load("navigation.html");
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"When I browse directly to the file and open with IE, the navigation.html file isn't loaded."* Don't do that. When you use this code live on the web, you won't be accessing it using a local file path, you'll be using a webserver that knows how to properly respond to ajax requests. (or, if that's not the case and this is to be used on the filesystem, get ready to type that header directly into all of your html files)

Comment: Open up your IIS and create a website. Point the website to your project folder. If your site is purely html, then you shouldn't need to worry about IIS pool settings etc ... Hosting your site on IIS will allow you to browse your site through localhost:ThePortYouHaveSetInIIS

Comment: your browser can not access the local file system (for obvious security reasons) so you should serve that `navigation.html` file trough a (local) webserver, which is exactly what VS is doing, judging by the `localhost` in the path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments, I intended to use the raw HTLM as a demo on a laptop without a webserver. But I see now that the AJAX request will need a webserver to work?

Answer (score 0):

You must take a loot at browser's console and XHR logging (Network Related). Most likely `.load()` simply can't find your `navigation.html` file.

I would guess that `.load()` should look for a file in a root folder, example:

`$('#nav-place-holder').load("/navigation.html");`

Another possible reason is security related. As correctly stated on comments by *[Pevara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340674/pevara)*,  your browser simply can't access the file.

As far as I'm aware, there are some security settings in *Google Chrome* and *Opera* that could be tweaked to work-around your problem.

1. In Google Chrome you must use option parameter upon running it `--allow-file-access-from-files`, for example: `"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`
2. In Opera you must set the flag `Allow File XMLHttpRequest` in `opera:config` of User Preferences.

Possibly there are options in IE as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if the problem is my security settings etc. or just that the AJAX aspect of this will always need a webserver to run? I intended to use the raw HTLM as a demo on a laptop without a webserver. But maybe that's not possible.